# Who is the old man that brings Ryu to Gouken's dojo in Street Fighter: Assassin's Fist?

Tags: character-identification, street-fighter

In [Street Fighter: Assassin's Fist](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3069212/), we learn in a flashback that Ryu was brought to Gouken's dojo by a mysterious old man.

I'm assuming he's supernatural in some way as he appears directly in front of Gouken, Gouken then looks away and looks back and the old man has suddenly moved maybe 30ft and is walking away into the distance.

Who is he?

Is this a character developed just for the movie, or is he someone is from Street Fighter lore?

I got my hands on a copy of the 143min uncut version and his identity is never revealed.

*btw, it's a briliant movie, you should see it if you can*

**UPDATE**

As Iankill suggested in the comments, he could be a reference to [Shen Long](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheng_Long), who was actually never a real character, more of an April Fool's joke / urban legend resulting from a mistranslation of something Ryu says in game.

Comment: I think its a reference to Sheng Long, as he's supposed to be a mysterious character of legend.

Comment: @Iankill Well he's pretty much an urban legend with some connection to Ryu right? So I guess it could be him...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character's name is Goma, Goutetsu's long-lost brother. The director already explained this in a Q&A session vid. The character was created specifically for the movie, but since he's become popular amongst fans like myself, we might possibly see him appear in a future SF game.

Comment: Oh yeah... Goutetsu mentions his brother alright. Totally forgot about that. They have a sequel in production for 2015/2016. He might appear in that.

Cheers Kevin